Cannot assign requested address Mysql Apache PHP Google Cloud
Tengo 2 servidores uno con apache y otro con mysql en rocky linux 8, ambos en google cloud conectados mediante una VLAN interna, cuando ejecuto procesos que hacen muchas consultas a la base de datos recibo el error "Cannot assign requested address" y el puerto 3306 deja de escuchar al servidor de apache (desde mi computador puedo hacerle consultas y me responde el servidor mysql), pense que era el max_connections de mysql lo configure en 5.000 pero no paso las 200-300 conexiones en simultaneo así que eso no soluciono mi problema,
Alguien me podría ayudar?

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. No logro entender que quieres decir con "el puerto 3306 deja de escuchar al servidor de apache". Por un lado, un puerto no escucha a algo en particular. Por otro lado, el mensaje "cannot assign requested address" usualmente viene acompañado de más información. Además, sería útil saber si este error se ve del lado del servidor o del lado del cliente (de la conexión que no se establece).
